# Setting CRS of raster to EPSG 3035 using R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r

I am trying to set the CRS of a raster file with the following code:

```
library(raster)
r<-raster(xmn=0,xmx=10,ymn=0,ymx=10)
crs(r)<-CRS("+init=epsg:3035")
```

The warning message is:

```
Warning message:
In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO") :
  Discarded datum European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989 in CRS definition
```

How can I succesfully change the CRS to EPSG 3035?

If I set the CRS to WGS84 I don't get any warning.

Comment: Its only a warning, so the CRS should be set. Is it? http://rgdal.r-forge.r-project.org/articles/CRS_projections_transformations.html for more info on changes in CRS in R because PROJ.

Comment: Yes, it's "just" a warning but I cannot intersect the resulting raster with any other sf-geometry. The error message is that the CRS are not equal, even though the features are both set to 3035.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. The code works perfectly on my system; no warning whatsoever and raster with CRS = `+init=epsg:3035 +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`. System Info: LinuxMint19.3 + R3.6.3 + raster3.1-5 + sp1.4-2 + rgdal1.5-10

Comment: You should be aware that due to changes in PROJ that the EPSG definition will no longer be supported at something in the near future.

Comment: @Jeffery Evans: I think the disabling of proj.4 strings with proj version 8 is a general problem where the current proj developers are only promoting their own perspective. However, they do not take into account the existing code around the world, especially existing libraries. This is not a good development and advice like "you should change your code does not help in principle" (keyword sustainability).

Answer (score 1):

Im suffering from the same problem. Tried to read in raster files with CRS set to EPSG:3067. Same message of ETRS89 datum being discarded arises.

One can add manually the information to the crs-string. I just do not believe that this actually fixes the problem.

```
#EXAMPLE OF ADDING DATUM INFO TO CRS STRING

library(raster)

file = raster("yourFilePath)
crsInfo <- slot(file, "crs")
slot(crsInfo, "projargs") <- paste0(slot(crsInfo, "projargs"), " +datum=GRS80")
slot(file, "crs") <- crsInfo
```

Comment: Wow, that is convoluted when `proj4string(x) <- "+init=epsg:3035"` do the same thing. The error is arising due to the transition to WKT projection definitions and the changes in GDAL and PROJ. Just ignore them.